# Exceptions Not Being Thrown In Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, exception

For some reason my exceptions arent being thrown anymore in Visual Studio.  I get the error in JSON on the response, but Visual Studio in debug mode no longer throws an error and stops Visual Studio at that error when it happens.

I have looked into posts like this:

[Visual Studio not stopping on an exception being thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410505/visual-studio-not-stopping-on-an-exception-being-thrown)

But I just want to reset where I was before, not enable exceptions one by one.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To reset the exceptions settings, go to Debug>Exceptions and click "Reset All."

You can also drill down and control what happens for different types of exceptions.

[image: Visual Studio 2012 menu selection]
[image: Visual Studio 2012 exceptions dialog]

#### update

You mentioned that you are missing the User-Unhandled column. In that case, you may need to set this:

[image]

Comment: I actually did this.  Nothing happens and I dont have a User-unhandled column anymore.  Thanks for the screenshot though.

Comment: I think I found it thanks! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560497/exception-window-in-vs-net-2010-is-missing-the-user-unhandled-column

Comment: thanks alot, have been thinking about fixing this for quite some time now. And now I finally did it! :)

Comment: UI looks different sins VS 2019(?) but it still more or less the same and still working.

Answer (score 4):

`Cntrl + Alt + E` (Or **Debug -> Exceptions**)
Then select "**Reset All**", that will return the default exceptions on.

Answer (score 2):

I hit a problem where it wasn't stopping on an exception and resetting the exception settings worked for me. To expand on Jay's answer above, in VS 2019 that option to reset is in a slightly different place (arguably a step backward compared to how it was before, it's clearer there).

Go to debug -> windows -> exception settings

The reset button is now this icon here:

[image: Reset Exception Settings]