# App crashes after loading images

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am loading about 20 to 100 images in a grid .

I am resizing it before loading on UI.

It works fine initially but crashes after 2 to 3 times navigation ( using Pushasync and Popasync)

Please help

```
protected async override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        try
        {
               await show_Thumbnail();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            error=ex.Message;
        }}
```

I caught the exception but it doesn't show any exceptions but crashes the app.

Comment: Is there some kind of error message? Exception? Something in the output window? This is little information to go on. Please also refer to the ['how to as a question'](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for some tips.

Comment: Code & Exception Message?

Comment: No exception message. Please help

Comment: Do a Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);  There needs to be an error message

Comment: Check these questions, it may be why you don't see exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17311171/exceptions-not-being-thrown-in-visual-studio http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4560497/exception-window-in-vs-net-2010-is-missing-the-user-unhandled-column

Answer (score 1):

You can't load 20 to 100 images in `Grid`. Mobile phones do not have gigabytes and gigabytes of memories like desktops. You should use `ListView` only to display more than 4-5 items on screen. When you specify `DataTemplate` in `ListView` along with `RecycleStrategy`, only visible images will be kept in memory and rest will be deallocated automatically.

Also search for `GridView` kind of controls which supports item recycling.

Comment: Why can't you load 20 or more?